# Cambiar valor de un atributo en ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo la siguiente consulta:
Quiero saber si es posible utilizar una variable en un atributo en ajax, no se si me explico, pero en el siguiente código trataré de explicar:

```
<script>
function active_change_update(ruta, id, status, campo)
{
    if(status==1 || status==null){
        var estado = 0;
    }else{
        var estado = 1;
    }

    var dato = { 
        'id': id,
        '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        //por defecto utilizaba active ya que en mi tabla producto esta asi y lo unico que quiero modificar es el valor del active
        //hasta aqui todo bien
        'active': estado
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: ruta,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dato,
        success:function(data) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Como pueden ver yo quiero modificar el valor del active, pero me di cuenta que esta función puedo utilizarla para modificar varios atributos de otras tablas, por ejemplo el "vendido" o "entregado" que también son booleanos.
Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
function active_change_update(ruta, id, status, campo)
{
    if(status==1 || status==null){
        var estado = 0;
    }else{
        var estado = 1;
    }

    //recibo el valor de "campo" que en este caso es "vendido" y quiero pasar ese atributo al json

    var dato = { 
        'id': id,
        '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        //de esta manera
        campo: estado
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: ruta,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dato,
        success:function(data) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Absolutamente esta no es la manera correcta y he buscado varias alternativas, les agradecería mucho si me ayudaran con esto. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Comment: No da ningún error, nada más actualiza el campo a vacío(null).

Comment: Y si tan solo creas `var estado` fuera del `if`

Comment: El estado no es el atributo que quiero modificar, lo que quiero modificar es 'campo' el atributo que esta dentro de la cadena json, donde coloque el comentario //de esta manera, es ahi donde quiero colocar el valor que recibo en la funcion

Comment: como **json** es cadena puedes concatenar tu objeto, por ejemplo creas un variable llamada  `var campo = "active" `, el cual sera sera concatenado con tu objeto `var dato = "{ 'id': id,'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'," + campo +" : estado}"`, prueba de esa manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero crear una cadena de texto **dinamico**, lo haces concatenando los valores.

tiene que ser con **comillas simples** como muestra el ejemplo

luego para poder enviar tus datos por ajax se necesita convertir tu cadena a Json con `JSON.Parse()`

tu codigo quedaria de la sigueinte manera:

```
function active_change_update(ruta, id, status, campo)
{
    if(status==1 || status==null){
        var estado = 0;
    }else{
        var estado = 1;
    }

    //aqui colocamos la cadena donde concatenas los valores y atributos dinamicos dinamicos

    var cadena = '{ "id": "' + id + '","_token": "1","' + campo + '": "' + estado + '"}'

    //aqui usamos el JSON.Parse para convertir tu cadena a Json

    var dato = JSON.parse(cadena);

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: ruta,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dato,
        success:function(data) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

el resultado :

> {id: "1", _token: "1", Estado: "1"}

solo falta adecuar tu token.

Espero que te ayude, saludos.